# Azure AD B2C API calls vs Claims email format

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Different account types (external identity/B2C Member/B2C Guest) have email addresses populated in different locations (username/primary email/alternative email). Should this be of concern, or are all emails passed in email string collection claim? We might build some reporting around B2C – how would they show up in API calls vs claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a local or social account, the built-in policies issue the "emails" claim for this account. For a local account, this claim is mapped from the "signInNames/emailAddress" attribute. For a social account, it is mapped from the "otherMails" attribute.

For a member or guest user (i.e. one that is created using the Azure Active Directory > Users and groups > All users > New user or New guest user blade), the built-in policies can't issue claims for this user (because it can't log them in).